# What is the difference between these two ways of passing arguments?

Tags: python

In Python, these two examples do the same thing:

```
from tkinter import Label
widget = Label(None, text='Hello')
widget.pack()
widget.mainloop()

from tkinter import Label
widget = Label(None,'Hello')
widget.pack()
widget.mainloop()
```

I think `Label` is a class, and when I try to create an instance of that class, I always do the same thing as in the last code example. I feel strange about the meaning of `text='Hello'`. Could anyone please tell me about that?

Comment: Here you do not create a class, you create an object by instantiating the class `Label`.

Comment: @glglgl oh..I mean create an instance of a class.. You are right...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`text='Hello'` means you're explicitly passing the value `'Hello'` to a **keyword argument** `text` in the function arguments.

`Label(None,'Hello')` means `'Hello'` is passed to the second positional argument in the function definition(no matter what the name of that variable is)

```
>>> def func(first, second):
...     print first, second
...     
>>> func('foo', 'text')
foo text
>>> func('foo', second = 'text')
foo text
```

With keyword arguments the order of calling doesn't matter, but all keyword arguments must come after positional arguments.

```
>>> def func(first, second, third):
    print first, second, third
...     
>>> func('foo', third = 'spam', second = 'bar')
foo bar spam
```

Here `first` gets the value `'foo'` because of it's position, while `second` and `third` got their values because they were passed those values by explicitly using their names.

For more details read docs: http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

Comment: + 1 Also known as "Named Parameter Association" in other languages.

Answer (score 14):

> I feel strange about the meaning of text='Hello'. Could anyone please tell me about that?

It is a [named argument](http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html) or [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Named arguments allow to pass arguments to functions in any order by not only passing the argument value, but also the argument name.

Answer (score 7):

As others said, this is a `keyword argument`. Pragmatically, the difference between specifying or not the argument is simply which argument is going to be used.

For example, if you had a function with 3 arguments, and only passed one, or two of them, you'd have to specify which argument you were using, in case they were not the first ones in your definition.

```
def f(a = "a", b = "b", c = "c"):
    print a, b, c

>>> f("x")
x b c
>>> f("x", "y")
x y c
>>> f("x", c = "y")
x b y
```

Answer (score 6):

`text` in this case is a [keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments), which means that it is optional. If you don't supply it explicitly, a default value will be supplied automatically.

Comment: You can pass non-optional arguments by keyword. Ashwini Chaudhary's example code does this, for instance. I think you're confusing them, because the syntax for a call with keyword arguments looks similar to a definition with default parameters: `foo(bar=baz)`.

Comment: I'm aware of the nuance, but left it out of the answer since the linked docs explain things pretty well. Note also that with some functions it's not a good idea to use keyword arguments even when it's possible to do so, see  [randrange](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/random.html#random.randrange).